# PowerBI: How to Export Table Headers with Column Quality

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm new to PowerBI, and am working on a large database. I am attempting to prepare the data in the PowerQuery Editor.

I would like to code as many steps as possible, as analysing each column manually is extremely time consuming.

My coding goals (in order of priority):

1. For each query I would like to get their column quality.
2. Ideally, I would like to export the header names with the column quality, so that I can determine which are relevant. Furthermore, I can also use the column names to determine which column relationships might be relevant. The database is huge, so simply just importing all the data and trying to work with it from their is not feasible, in fact PowerBI comes up with the error that I don't have enough free memory.

I have VBA and some SQL experience.

I know I have a lot to learn w.r.t. PowerBI, and I am working on it, but need some guidance and direction, also on what is possible/feasible.

Any contructive hints, advice, or feedback would be appreciated - thank you!

Comment: If the data is to big to import, consider using direct query mode

Answer (score 1):

Use Table.Profile() on each table and load to the data model.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-profile